# Enable sort not working on PCF column on UI

Tags: guidewire, gosu

Trying to sort a column in a Row Iterator. It looks like I am able to sort all columns that are coming from the entities directly but not the columns that are returning data from a function. This is the function I am using:

```
    function getActivityPriority(renewal : Renewal) : Priority {
  var getActivityPriorities = renewal?.Policy?.AllOpenActivities?.last()

  if (getActivityPriorities != null) {
    return getActivityPriorities?.Priority
  }
  return null
}
```

On the Column I have the value set to getActivityPriority(renewal). This will not let me sort the column on the UI.

This is a PCF page that lists out the renewals and the latest activity opened on that renewal. So I am trying to add the Activity Priority. Which is working. But it will not allow me to sort the column. I have enable sort set as "true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting on the UI can only be achieved for columns that are directly associated to the entity which you are using(root entity). For columns returned through functions we cannot do this.